# javascript custom scope binding function

Tags: javascript, scope, bind

I am reading this article - <s>http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/</s> - where a custom bind function is made.

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(scope) {
  var _function = this;

  return function() {
    return _function.apply(scope, arguments);
  }
}

alice = {
  name: "alice"
}

eve = {
  talk: function(greeting) {
    console.log(greeting + ", my name is " + this.name);
  }.bind(alice) // <- bound to "alice"
}

eve.talk("hello");
// hello, my name is alice
```

My question is this line in particlar

```
 return function() {
    return _function.apply(scope, arguments);
  }
```

Why is the **return** in _function.apply(scope, arguments); there?  And what is it doing and what is being returned?
I removed that return and it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Why is the return in _function.apply(scope, arguments); there? And what is it doing and what is being returned? I removed that return and it still works.
```

This is there in case you want to return a value. Currently your talk function is not returning any value so you don't need it. if you change your talk function to

```
eve = {
  talk: function(greeting) {
    return ( greeting + ", my name is " + this.name) ;
  }.bind(alice) // <- bound to "alice"
}

console.log(eve.talk("hello"));
```

Now you will realize why return is required

Answer (score 1):

It returns the result of applying the original function (the one being bound). When you make `_function.apply`, the `_function` will be called with `scope` as the context, so inside the function `this` will always refer to the `scope`.

The second parameter `arguments` is there to pass all the arguments to the original function. And the `return` statement is there to make sure that the value returned from the original function call will also be returned from the bound function call.

Answer (score 0):

In the return you simply return new function. You close the `scope` and `_function` in the scope of the returned anonymous function. It's called closure - all variables visible in the parent function (the one which return the anonymous one) are visible in the returned function.

Here is your example:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(scope) {
  var _function = this;

  return function() {
    return _function.apply(scope, arguments);
  }
};

function foo() {
    console.log(this.foobar);
}

var bar = {
   foobar: 'baz'
};

foo = foo.bind(bar);
```

So now step by step: `foo.bind(bar);` returns the function:

```
  function() {
    return _function.apply(scope, arguments);
  }
```

`_function` is `foo`, `scope` is the `bind` argument - `bar`. `arguments` is something like an array (not exactly) which contains all arguments of a function, so by: `foo()`, your `this` will be the scope provided as first argument of `apply`. If you use `foo(1,2,3)` arguments will contain `1,2,3`.

The logged result will be `baz`.